# Por qué no ordena los colores correctamente?

Tags: javascript, html

escribí este programa para que se ordenen los cuadrados de colores automáticamente, pero no puedo lograrlo, a veces funciona, otras no.

Básicamente, se ven filas de cuadrados de dsintintos colores, y cuando el usuario presiona un botón, se emepiezan a ordenar hasta quedar los cuadrados de los mismos colores juntos.

A veces funciona, otras veces no, entiendo que hay un grave error de lógica en todo el desarrollo, pero no puedo detectar de qué forma hacerlo correctamente Seguramente encuentren que el código es muy básico y debe haber fomar muchísimo mejores de hacerlo, pero creo que la lógica no esta TAN errada.

Alguien podría hercharle un vistazo?? Si lo corren tal cual está, debería funcionar en cualquier explorador.
Gracias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        #header{
            padding: 5%;
        }
        .foo{
            height: 70px;
            width: 70px;
            display: inline-block;
            color: black;
            font-size: large;
            margin: .5%;
            margin-top: .5%;
            text-align: center;
            /*border-radius: 50%;
            /*box-shadow: .5px .5px 15px black;
            box-shadow: inset;*/
        }
    </style>
    <head>
    </head>
        <body /**onload="timer()">
            <header id="header">
            <div class='foo' id="foo0"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo1"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo2"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo3"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo4"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo5"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo6"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo7"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo8"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo9"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo10"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo11"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo12"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo13"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo14"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo15"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo16"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo17"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo18"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo19"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo20"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo21"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo22"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo23"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo24"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo25"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo26"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo27"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo28"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo29"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo30"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo31"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo32"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo33"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo34"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo35"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo36"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo37"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo38"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo39"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo40"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo41"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo42"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo43"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo44"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo45"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo46"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo47"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo48"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo49"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo50"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo51"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo52"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo53"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo54"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo55"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo56"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo57"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo58"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo59"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo60"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo61"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo62"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo63"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo64"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo65"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo66"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo67"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo68"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo69"><p></p></div>
            --></header>
         
            <input type="button" value = 'spine!!!!!!!!!' onclick="JavasCript:timer"> 
            <input type="button" value = 'stop' onclick="JavasCript:stopper()"> 
            
            <script type="text/javascript">
           
           //let element = document.getElementById('foo1');
                //if(element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'){
                //    element.style.backgroundColor='green'
                //}

                //let element = document.getElementById('foo2').nextSibling.value; // #foo3
                //document.getElementById('foo2').previousSibling; // #foo1
               
                var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
                
                let colors = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange']
                
                let x = [];
                for (let i = 0; i<divs.length; i++){
                     x[i] = "foo" + i;
                };
                
                let z = 0;
                function changeBackColor(x){
                        this.element = document.getElementById(x[z]);
                        element.style.backgroundColor =  colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];;
                        z++
                };

                    function generateId(){
                        return "foo" + getRandomInteger(3);
                    };

                    function getRandomInteger(upperLimit) // Gets a random number on less than upperLimit
                    {
                        var result;
                        result = Math.random();
                        result = result * (upperLimit + 1);
                        result = Math.floor(result);
                        return result;
                    }

                    for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
                        changeBackColor(x);
                        let arr = [];
                        //arr[i] = 
                    };               
                    function insertAfter(newNode, existingNode) {
                        existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
                    }
                    function spine(){
                            let zeta = x.length;
                            let header = document.getElementById('foo2').parentNode;
                            let element = document.getElementById(x[0]);
                            let element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;    
                            let element_next = element.nextElementSibling;    
                            
                            
                            for (let i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++){
                                try{
                                    if(element.style.backgroundColor != element_next.style.backgroundColor){
                                        insertAfter(element, element_next); 
                                        element_next = element.nextElementSibling;
                                        element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;
                                        console.log('distinto')
                                        
                                    }else{ //if(element.style.backgroundColor == element_next.style.backgroundColor){            
                                        element = document.getElementById(x[i]);
                                        element_next = element.nextElementSibling;               
                                        element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;
                                        //console.log('igual')
                                }
                                }catch(err){
                                        console.log(x[i]);
                                                         
                                    //}else{
                                    //    break;
                                    //}
                                    
                                }
                             
                        }
                    }
                    //    element = document.getElementById(x[x.length]);
                    //    let element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;
                    //    //for(let i = 1 ; i < x.length ; i++){
                    //        while(element.style.backgroundColor != element_prev.style.backgroundColor){
                    //            header.insertBefore(element, element_prev);
                    //            
                    //            element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;    
                    //        }    
                    //    //}
                   
                        
                    //function timer(){
                    //  setInterval(spine, 10),5);
                    //        };
                      
                    let timer = setTimeout(() => {
                        setInterval(spine, 10);
                    }, 3000);

                    function stopper(){
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    };


                            
                            //while(zeta < divs.length-1){                                    
                            //        if(element.style.backgroundColor != element_prev.style.backgroundColor){                                                  
                            //            header.insertBefore(element, element_prev);
                            //            element_prev = element.nextElementSibling;       
                            //        } else {
                            //            element = element.nextElementSibling;
                            //            element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;
                            //        };
                            //       zeta++;
                            //};
                     
                
                    //var element = document.getElementById("foo1");
                //console.log(element.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor == 'green');

                //document.write(element.innerHTML)
                //for (let i = 0 ; i<divs.length; i++){
                //    if(element.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor == 'green'){
                //        alert('OK')
                //    } else {
                //        alert('not')
                //    }
                //}
                </script>

            
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mí funcionó cambiando la forma de lanzar el timer. Tal vez esperando a que cargue todo el documento antes de empezar (y evitando esos `javasCript:` que no dicen nada), funcione correctamente.

También eliminé unos comentarios que estaban por ahí sueltos y quité el onload del body para que el document.ready() sea quien ponga el listener y, cuando todo esté en su lugar en el documento, cargado, comience la ejecución.

PD. Sí, usé el `.ready()` de JQuery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">    
    </script>
    <style>
        #header{
            padding: 5%;
        }
        .foo{
            height: 70px;
            width: 70px;
            display: inline-block;
            color: black;
            font-size: large;
            margin: .5%;
            margin-top: .5%;
            text-align: center;
            /*border-radius: 50%;
            /*box-shadow: .5px .5px 15px black;
            box-shadow: inset;*/
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <header id="header">
            <div class='foo' id="foo0"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo1"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo2"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo3"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo4"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo5"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo6"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo7"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo8"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo9"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo10"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo11"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo12"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo13"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo14"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo15"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo16"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo17"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo18"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo19"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo20"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo21"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo22"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo23"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo24"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo25"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo26"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo27"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo28"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo29"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo30"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo31"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo32"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo33"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo34"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo35"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo36"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo37"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo38"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo39"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo40"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo41"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo42"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo43"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo44"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo45"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo46"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo47"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo48"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo49"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo50"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo51"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo52"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo53"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo54"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo55"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo56"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo57"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo58"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo59"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo60"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo61"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo62"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo63"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo64"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo65"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo66"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo67"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo68"><p></p></div>
            <div class='foo' id="foo69"><p></p></div>
            </header>
         
            <input type="button" value = 'spine!!!!!!!!!' onclick="timer();"/> 
            <input type="button" value = 'stop' onclick="stopper();"/> 

<script type="text/javascript">
           
           //let element = document.getElementById('foo1');
                //if(element.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'){
                //    element.style.backgroundColor='green'
                //}

                //let element = document.getElementById('foo2').nextSibling.value; // #foo3
                //document.getElementById('foo2').previousSibling; // #foo1
               
                var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); 
                
                let colors = ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'orange']
                
                let x = [];
                for (let i = 0; i<divs.length; i++){
                     x[i] = "foo" + i;
                };
                
                let z = 0;
                function changeBackColor(x){
                        this.element = document.getElementById(x[z]);
                        element.style.backgroundColor =  colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];;
                        z++
                };

                    function generateId(){
                        return "foo" + getRandomInteger(3);
                    };

                    function getRandomInteger(upperLimit) // Gets a random number on less than upperLimit
                    {
                        var result;
                        result = Math.random();
                        result = result * (upperLimit + 1);
                        result = Math.floor(result);
                        return result;
                    }

                    for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
                        changeBackColor(x);
                        let arr = [];
                        //arr[i] = 
                    };               
                    function insertAfter(newNode, existingNode) {
                        existingNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, existingNode.nextSibling);
                    }
                    function spine(){
                            let zeta = x.length;
                            let header = document.getElementById('foo2').parentNode;
                            let element = document.getElementById(x[0]);
                            let element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;    
                            let element_next = element.nextElementSibling;    
                            
                            
                            for (let i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++){
                                try{
                                    if(element.style.backgroundColor != element_next.style.backgroundColor){
                                        insertAfter(element, element_next); 
                                        element_next = element.nextElementSibling;
                                        element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;
                                        console.log('distinto')
                                        
                                    }else{ //if(element.style.backgroundColor == element_next.style.backgroundColor){            
                                        element = document.getElementById(x[i]);
                                        element_next = element.nextElementSibling;               
                                        element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;
                                        //console.log('igual')
                                }
                                }catch(err){
                                        console.log(x[i]);
                                                         
                                    //}else{
                                    //    break;
                                    //}
                                    
                                }
                             
                        }
                    }
                    //    element = document.getElementById(x[x.length]);
                    //    let element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;
                    //    //for(let i = 1 ; i < x.length ; i++){
                    //        while(element.style.backgroundColor != element_prev.style.backgroundColor){
                    //            header.insertBefore(element, element_prev);
                    //            
                    //            element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;    
                    //        }    
                    //    //}
                   
                        
                    //function timer(){
                    //  setInterval(spine, 10),5);
                    //        };

                    function stopper(){
                        clearInterval(timer);
                    };
                    
                    $( document ).ready(function() {
                      let timer = setTimeout(() => {
                        setInterval(spine, 10);
                      }, 3000);
                      console.log( "ready!" );
                    });


                            
                            //while(zeta < divs.length-1){                                    
                            //        if(element.style.backgroundColor != element_prev.style.backgroundColor){                                                  
                            //            header.insertBefore(element, element_prev);
                            //            element_prev = element.nextElementSibling;       
                            //        } else {
                            //            element = element.nextElementSibling;
                            //            element_prev = element.previousElementSibling;
                            //        };
                            //       zeta++;
                            //};
                     
                
                    //var element = document.getElementById("foo1");
                //console.log(element.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor == 'green');

                //document.write(element.innerHTML)
                //for (let i = 0 ; i<divs.length; i++){
                //    if(element.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor == 'green'){
                //        alert('OK')
                //    } else {
                //        alert('not')
                //    }
                //}
         </script>
            
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta. Lo corrí 5 veces y funcionó en 4 ocasiones.